# How can I rotate my BoxCollider2D 360 degrees around other colliders while maintaining a constant forward direction?

Tags: unity, rotation, dotween

I'm trying to get my 2D character to rotate around colliders based on the current ground normal (sort of like in Mario Galaxy) detected by `Physics2D.CircleCast`, which I believe automatically interpolates the normals between two surfaces sharing a convex edge (e.g. the sharp edges of a `BoxCollider2D`). I also want my character to maintain a constant forward direction, in this case, `transform.right`.

To achieve this I'm setting my `transform.eulerAngles.z` to the value created by `Vector2.Angle(hit.normal, Vector2.up)`, but the problem is that this value is only accurate half of the time. If my character is moving around a circle, for example, only one half of the circle will provide an accurate rotation; the second half of the circle rotates me in the opposite direction. I'm not very comfortable with rotations or quaternions, but I've noticed that my z rotation will go from 0 to -180 on the "correct" half of the circle, and then start going in reverse again (-179, -178, etc.) on the other half. I've also noticed that the value shown in the inspector for my z rotation is not the same as the value I get when logging it to the console (console says 270, inspector shows -90).

```
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class RotationTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 5;
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask rayMask;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CheckForTerrainAndRotate();
    }

    private void CheckForTerrainAndRotate()
    {
        Vector2 direction = transform.right;
        transform.Translate(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        float circleCastRadius = boxCollider.bounds.extents.x + 0.05f;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, circleCastRadius, -transform.up, 5, rayMask);

        if (!hit)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
            return;
        }

        // Sets rotation using transform's euler angles
        transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -Vector2.Angle(hit.normal, Vector2.up)), 0.1f, RotateMode.Fast);
    }
}
```

I'm using the `DOTween` library to handle lerping between two rotations, but am also having the same issue without it.

Comment: [Vector2.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html): Note: The angle returned will always be between 0 and 180 degrees, because the method returns the smallest angle between the vectors. Maybe you need [Vector2.SignedAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html)

Comment: @Mangata This actually works; I didn't even know about `Vector2.SignedAngle`. But I still don't understand the discrepancy in z rotation between what I see in the inspector and in `Debug.Log`.

Comment: The values in inspector are euler angles. The actual rotation of transform is a quaternion. They are different values in memery, and they affect each other. Euler angles are "normalized" when generated from quaternions so that each value is in [0,360). `270` and `-90` are same actually.

Comment: @Mangata I recommend posting this as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vector2.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html):

> Note: The angle returned will always be **between 0 and 180 degrees**, because the method returns the smallest angle between the vectors.

Maybe you need [Vector2.SignedAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html):

> Note: The angle returned will always be **between -180 and 180 degrees**, because the method returns the smallest angle between the vectors.

Why *the value shown in the inspector for my z rotation is not the same as the value I get when logging it to the console*?

Because the values in inspector are euler angles. The actual rotation of transform is a quaternion. They are *different* values in memery, and they affect each other. Euler angles are "normalized" when generated from quaternions so that each value is in [0,360). So `270` and `-90` are *same* actually.